# How to identify names of columns having duplicate values in R

Tags: r

The dataframe has columns which consists of duplicate values.
How do we identify the colnames which have duplicate value and their count.

data set :

```
A  B  C
1  2  a
2  3  b
3  4  a
1  5  c
```

I need output like

columns having duplicate values are A(2) and C(2)

I have tried duplicated(), it returns a vector.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `sapply` to loop column wise  find the `duplicated` elements and take `sum` of it.

```
colSums(sapply(df, function(x) duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)))

#A B C 
#2 0 2
```

If you need only non-zero column you could do

```
vals <- colSums(sapply(df, function(x) 
                duplicated(x)|duplicated(x, fromLast = TRUE)))
vals[vals!= 0]
#A C 
#2 2
```

---

Using `dplyr` we can do the same with `summarise_all`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  summarise_all(~sum(duplicated(.) | duplicated(., fromLast = TRUE))) %>%
  select_if(~. != 0)

#  A C
#1 2 2
```

Answer (score 1):

To test if there are duplicate values in a column one can compare the number of unique values with the number of values in the column:

```
D <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE, text=
"A  B  C
1  2  a
2  3  b
3  4  a
1  5  c")
names(D)[sapply(D, function(x) length(unique(x)))!=nrow(D)]
```

or

```
names(D)[sapply(D, function(x) any(duplicated(x)))]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can loop over the columns and find `any` duplicates with `table` to identify the column names

```
names(df1)[sapply(df1, function(x) any(table(x) > 1))]
#[1] "A" "C"
```

---

Or another `base R` solution would be

```
names(Filter(anyDuplicated, df1))
#[1] "A" "C"
```

---

Or with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
names(df1)[!!map_int(df1, anyDuplicated)]
#[1] "A" "C"
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(A = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L), B = 2:5, C = c("a", "b", 
   "a", "c")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```